# In production server running on https but in Live(On Internet) it's shows http only

Tags: http, tomcat, https, ssl-certificate, liferay

I am working on Liferay with Tomcat 7.0+.
My Web application is Live with www.hpmc.in.

I have installed SSL Certificate successfully and i have also make relevant changes in server.xml and web.xml in tomcat/conf/ folder.

In Production server request is redirect to https://localhost:8080/____ but in live it's shows only http://hpmc.in/

Please help me.

Server.xml

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol"
           maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true"
           keystoreFile="XXX/XXX/XXXX.jks" keystorePass="XXXX"
           clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" />
```

In web.xml I have add following lines.

```
    <security-constraint>
<web-resource-collection>
<web-resource-name>HPMC Application</web-resource-name>
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</web-resource-collection>
<user-data-constraint>
<transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
</user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

[Production Server URL Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HvsUm.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all,

> Why are you using port `8080` for `https` traffic?

This (`8080`) port and `80` are intended for the use of non-secured data (`8080` for **internal** and `80` for **external**). You should be using `443/8443` for `https` traffic, which is standard for Tomcat secured (SSL/TLS) data.

Answer (score 0):

You also would like to test the following property:

```
web.server.protocol=https
```

https://docs.liferay.com/ce/portal/7.0-latest/propertiesdoc/portal.properties.html

From your comments I am not sure if it is behind a proxy, if it is you might want to check: https://www.e-systems.tech/docker-images/-/knowledge_base/docker-images/liferay-behind-a-reverse-proxy

I guess you are doing this cause I could not connect to the address you provided on 8080, only 80. so this is either a proxy, missing configs in the config you provided or a weird config. as 8080 is leading to ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT, I would think you are not bringing this connector up, or it is being blocked.

To assist you further more information is required.